# Eager loading with parameters - laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eager-loading

I have `Banks` table and separate table with `services`

```
$bank = Banks::find(1);
echo $bank->service(1); // print bank with that service (serviceId 1)
```

It is posible to eager load all banks with service_id =1 ..somewhat like

```
Bank::with('service(1)')->get();
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean to do like this **where service_id in (1)** inside model  ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure! The `with` method accepts a closure to filter eager loading.

```
Bank::with(array('service' => function($query){
    $query->where('id', 1);
}))->get();
```

Comment: You can add/pass your own parameter using "use"
`
Bank::with(array('service' => function($query) use ($param){
    $query->where('id', $param);
}))->get();
`

Comment: @Tom, you saved my day! I have been looking for this for one hour and until now I haven't found anyone who specifies how to pass a parameter here. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use WhereIn to your Model and you shall pass any number inside the Array.

```
$Data = Banks::whereIn('service_id ', array(1, 2, 3))->get();
var_dump($Data);
```

I am using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) and you shall choose your own coloumn to get your need.

Docs : [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent), [Advance Where](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
return User::with(['posts' => function($query){
              $query->whereNotIn('id',[1]);
            }])
           ->get();
```